# jquery.dataTables very slow in ie 11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, datatable, datatables

A user has reported a strange problem, where after upgrading to ie 11, jquery.dataTables are very slow (20 - 40 seconds) to render. There are approximately 400 results, which seems resonable. And it runs VERY quickly in Chrome and FF.

After doing some diving, it turns out that any call to table sorter is causing server slowness.

We're using 1.9.4, although attempts at upgrading to 1.10 have not shown any performance improvements either.

The code is very straightforward:

```
$('#results_table').dataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 1, 12 ] },
            { 'sType': 'currency', 'aTargets': [8] }
        ],
        "aaSorting": [[19, 'asc'], [18, 'asc'], [16, 'desc'], [4, 'desc'], [13, 'desc'], [5, 'desc'], [14, 'desc'], [15, 'desc'], [3, 'asc'], [6, 'desc']]
    });
```

Any thoughts on improvements would would welcome.

Comment: It performs in under a second in FF and Chrome. 40 seconds in IE. This seems more like a specific bug than general slowness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly a fix, but it is a good work around. I switched to building an array of data and attaching that to dataTables instead of building dom elements.

Example:

```
$('#results_table').dataTable({
  "aaData":[[attrs], [attrs]], // an array of row data
   "aaSorting": [[19, 'asc'], [18, 'asc']],
   "aoColumns": [
       { "sClass": "center" },
       //... other class definitions
    ]
});
```

Comment: How much of a speed increase did you see from this?

Comment: I tried this on what was taking IE 4 seconds and now it is taking 2 seconds. Faster but firefox and chrome still do it in under a second. I am only dealing with a bit over 2000 records.

Comment: Mine actually went from 30 seconds down to 1. Not sure what the differences could be.

Comment: I added the defer rendering option and that made it go down to .5 seconds. It is an ugly fix but it does work till a better one comes along.